# indy gettickdiff64() 18446744073709551600 problem

Tags: indy

I found that the gettickdiff64 function sometimes results in 18446744073709551600 (or 18446744073709551601) and causes the
program to run incorrectly.
Normally does not have a result greater than 300000

what might this be about?
Should I always do extra checks against this problem?

it is 32 bit VCL application.
I use Delphi 10.4.1( its indy version 10.6.2.0 )
Running on: 64 bit Windows Server 2012 R2 Foundation / intel xeon cpu E3-1225 v5 3.3 Ghz.

The code structure is as follows:

```
TMyClass = class
 private
  //.............
  lastSetTime: uint64;
  critic: TCriticalSection;
 public
  //.............
  procedure setLastSetTime( ltime: uint64 );
  function getLastSetTime: uint64;
end;

procedure TMyClass.setLastSetTime( ltime: uint64 );
 begin
  critic.enter;
  try
    lastSetTime := ltime;
  finally
   critic.leave;
  end;
 end;

function TMyClass.getLastSetTime: uint64;
 begin
  critic.enter;
  try
    result := lastSetTime;
  finally
   critic.leave;
  end;
 end;


...........


procedure controlAll(); //------>this is called from within thread every 5 minutes
 var oki: boolean;
     starttime, tdiff, ltime: uint64;
     i: integer;
     myC, sC: TMyClass;
 begin
   oki := false;
   starttime := ticks64();
   while ( oki = false ) and ( gettickdiff64( starttime, ticks64 ) < 40000 ) do
   begin
     //.........
     //.........
     sC := nil;
     with myClassList.LockList do
     try
       if count > 0 then //---> has about 50000
       begin
         i := 0;
         while i < count do
         begin
           myC := TMyClass( items[ i ] );
           ltime := myC.getLastSetTime();
           tdiff := gettickdiff64( ltime, ticks64() );
           if tdiff > 50000 then
           begin
             logToFile( tdiff.ToString + ' ' + ltime.ToString );  //-----> every 5 minutes 50-60 log lines occur like this: 18446744073709551600 468528329
             //..........
             //.........
             sC := myC;
             delete( i );
             break;
           end; 
           inc( i );
         end;
       end;
     finally
       myClassList.UnlockList;
     end; 

     if sC = nil then oki := true
     else
     begin
       //..........
       //..........
     end;
   end;
 end;
```

The code structure that sets this value is as follows.

classListArray keeps all classes of TMyClass type grouped by server and channel number.
myClassList keeps all classes of type TMyClass attached one after the other without grouping.
classListArray is used to spend less CPU and process faster.
These two lists are not protected against each other when accessing classes.
Protection against each other is done only when adding and deleting classes.

```
classListArray: array[ 1..250, 1..12 ] of TThreadList;

//.................

procedure ServerExecute(AContext: TIdContext);
 var Ath: TMypeer;
     severNum, channelNum, clientNum, i, j, num: integer;
     pSize: word;
     stream: Tmemorystream;
     packageNum: byte;
 begin
   try
      Ath := TMypeer( AContext );

      serverNum  := Ath.getServerNum();
      channelNum := Ath.getChannelNum();

      Ath.SendQueue();

      if AContext.Connection.IOHandler.InputBufferIsEmpty then
        if not AContext.Connection.IOHandler.CheckForDataOnSource( 50 ) then Exit;
   
      clientNum := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadInt32( false );
      pSize := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadUInt16( false );

      stream := TMemorystream.create;
      try
        AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadStream( stream, pSize );

        stream.Seek( 0, soFromBeginning );
        if clientNum <> 0 then
        begin
          //...........
        end
        else
        begin 
          stream.ReadBuffer( packageNum, sizeof( packageNum ) );
          if packageNum = 10 then
          begin
            stream.ReadBuffer( num, sizeof( num ) );
            for i := 1 to num do
            begin
               stream.ReadBuffer( clientNum, sizeof( clientNum ) );
               with classListArray[ serverNum, channelNum ].LockList do
               try
                 if count > 0 then
                  for j := 0 to count - 1 do
                   begin
                     if TMyClass( items[ j ] ).getClientNum = clientNum then 
                     begin
                        TMyClass( items[ j ] ).setLastSetTime( ticks64 ); //**********
                        break;
                     end; 
                   end;
               finally
                 classListArray[ serverNum, channelNum ].unLockList;
               end;
            end;
          end
          else
          //.........
        end;
      finally
        stream.free;
      end;
   except on e:exception do
      begin
        if E is Eidexception then raise
        else
        begin
           logToFile( e.message );
           //..........
        end;
      end; 
   end;
 end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your log, `ltime` was `468528329` and `GetTickDiff64(ltime, Ticks64())` returned `18446744073709551600`.  Given the simple implementation of `GetTickDiff64()` (where `TIdTicks` is `UInt64`):

```pascal
function GetTickDiff64(const AOldTickCount, ANewTickCount: TIdTicks): TIdTicks;
{$IFDEF USE_INLINE}inline;{$ENDIF}
begin
  {This is just in case the TickCount rolled back to zero}
  if ANewTickCount >= AOldTickCount then begin
    Result := TIdTicks(ANewTickCount - AOldTickCount);
  end else begin
    Result := TIdTicks(((High(TIdTicks) - AOldTickCount) + ANewTickCount) + 1);
  end;
end;
```

The only way this code can return `18446744073709551600` given `AOldTickCount=468528329` is if `ANewTickCount` is either `18446744074178079929` or `468528313`.

Since VCL runs on Windows only, and on Windows `Ticks64()` is just a thin wrapper around the Win32 `GetTickCount64()` function on Vista and later, it is very unlikely that Windows would ever produce such an astronomically large number like `18446744074178079929` for the current tick counter (that would be 213503982340 days from bootup).  So it must have returned `468528313` instead, which is more reasonable (that is just 5.4 days from bootup).  That is **16ms less than** `ltime=468528329`, so `GetTickDiff64()` would assume that Windows' tick counter had exceeded `High(UInt64)` and wrapped back around to 0 (which is unlikely for a 64-bit tick counter to *ever* do in our lifetime).

So, you need to debug your code and figure out how `Ticks64()`/Windows could possibly return `468528329` and then later return `468528313`.  I suspect it is really not doing that, and that there is more likely a bug in your code that we can't see which is storing the wrong value into `TMyClass.lastSetTime` to begin with.

That being said, you might consider getting rid of the overhead of `TCriticalSection` and use [`TInterlocked`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SyncObjs.TInterlocked) instead to read/write your `UInt64` member atomically.

Or, try using Delphi's own [`TStopWatch`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Diagnostics.TStopwatch) instead of tracking ticks manually.